# JavaScript rule extension

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to extend Sonarqube with custom Javascript rules. I find that the documentation is fairly limited on this subject. The extension tutorials on sonarqube website show only the most basic stuff.

The only javadoc I could find is this one: http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/latest/apidocs/ and it doesn't cover anything about extending Javascript.

What I ultimately want to do is add a JS rule that will check for hardcoded secrets (such as passwords, api keys, etc). I already created one for Java, and that was a lot easier as I could take an already pre-made plugin and complete it with my custom regex.

The problematic spot that made me post here was actually this one:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   class VariableTree
location: package org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.tree.expression
```

I was following the same scheme as with Java and used 
`import org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.tree.expression.VariableTree;`
which is obviously wrong. I was not able to find the source code for this either... if anybody can point me to some secret doc stash or at least where I can find a javadoc for `org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api` that would be amazing!

Thanks very much for any help

Comment: Hey SONARQUBE 1 month in, could somebody show signs of life?